# Crop Contures of Image with OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, medical

I'm trying to find out the image size of the important part of a medical image as seen below. I am using OpenCV and Python.

[image]

I have to crop the image first to get rid of the black space around the image. 
Here is my Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image-000.png')

height, width, channels = img.shape     #shape of original image

height_2 = height * 7/100
width_2 = width * 15/100

img[0:height_2, 0:width_2] = [0, 0, 0]    #get rid of the watermark on the top left

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,15,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

_, contours, _= cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt = contours[0]

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

crop = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]

height_2, width_2, channels_2 = crop.shape
print "height: " + repr(height_2)
print "width: " + repr(width_2)


cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code works fine for the image above:

[image]

However when I want to use the same code for other images it doesnt work.
For example this doesnt work:

[image]

Do you know what I am doing wrong?
Your help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you find more then 1 contour in the second image. Just replace your line `cnt = contours[0]` with `cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)` and it will just get the biggest contour for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer! Works just fine!